# Java - catch call stack or break point from clicking on a GUI object

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jframe

Is there a way to see the "Call Stack" or have an application automatically hit a break point when the user clicks on a GUI object without previously setting up the breakpoint in the java code before running it?

I'm running a large GUI application on Netbeans12.0 that uses JFrame.

There's a part of the application that brings up a small dialog with HTML/CSS on it.  Part of the dialog has a HTML anchor tag that when the user clicks on that anchor the GUI does get updated.

I'm trying to find the code that acts on the click on the anchor tag.

I'm trying to search for the code myself but it is seemingly difficult to find.

Comment: Start at the portion of code you know gets executed, e.g. the GUI update or the listener on the HTML. Then work your way from there, i.e. either up or down the call stack/chain.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the GUI app?  Or can you get a build with debug symbols and source?  You can debug Java apps after they start, but they need to be compiled to allow it.  [JPDA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) is the protocol that Java apps can enable for remote/external debugging.   You can try also try the [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A `JEditorPane` can accept and act on a [`HyperlinkListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html)